# mysql: timestamp only one column when update char

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a log with timestamp in mysql.
For this I created a column tm with datatype timestamp.

It works fine and is updated every time I change something.

The problem is that it should only update when I set the exist column to '1'. Not when I change any column.
Here you can view my table ..:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
bez varchar(55) DEFAULT 'unknown',
type varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
exist char NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
tm TIMESTAMP
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
);
```

This is my UPDATE:

```
if ( isset($_GET["id"]) ) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "UPDATE admins SET exist='0' WHERE id=$id";
    $con->query($sql);
}

header("location: /index.php");
exit;
?>
```

So the UPDATE should change the timestamp and the exist.

Please dont tell me that i am open to sql injections, i know this and we have a security manager in this project who will change afterwards.

thanks for your help community!

Comment: ___Why make work for the security manager, do it right first time___ Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: _"So the UPDATE should change the timestamp and the exist."_ - why should _that_ statement change the timestamp, when you said you only wanted to do that when you set exist=1? _"Not when I change any column"_ - then it would really make more sense to not use this auto-update functionality for the timestamp, and just explicitly set it to `NOW()` in those few (one?) case(s) where you actually need it.

Comment: that was not even my question .. @RiggsFolly

Comment: @CBroe but when i change for example my bez the timestamp will update. how do you imagine that it will only be updated when I execute the UPDATE command?

Comment: You would have to disable the automatic update functionality. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: The alternative would be to add `tm = tm` to the SET clauses of _all_ your other UPDATE statements, to explicitly set the column to the value it already has.

Comment: @CBroe whats wrong with my syntax? it doesnt work:   `$sql = "UPDATE admins SET exist='1', tm=$tm WHERE id=$id";`

Comment: You are trying to use a variable `$tm`, instead of simply writing the column name.

Answer (score 0):

The `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` feature that is implicitly enabled on the first `TIMESTAMP` on a table is an all-or-nothing feature, it does not allow for the fine grained control you are aiming for.

The behavior you are looking for can only be accomplished by either explicitly setting the `TIMESTAMP` column value in the `UPDATE`, or by adding a trigger to the table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON admins FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.exists = 1 THEN 
    SET NEW.tm = NOW();
  END IF;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

and chang the column definition from

tm TIMESTAMP;

to

tm TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

or maybe

tm TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0;

or even

tm DATETIME;

to prevent the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` behavior.

Comment: where i have to insert the DELIMITER? php, inside mysql ?

Comment: i get this error in SQL

`ERROR 1362 (HY000): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger`

Comment: i guess i need a BEFORE which BEFORE would be useful

Comment: It needs to be a BEFORE trigger, not AFTER, indeed, I changed the answer accordingly.

Regarding the DELIMITER I assume that you execute DDL from the command line client. Changing the DELIMITER before a creating a trigger (or function / procedure) is necessary as the default query delimiter `;` is also the statement delimiter in trigger/function/procedure bodies ...

See also e.g. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters/